# Database username not changed in Laravel 5 production mode

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I write code with Laravel 5.3 in Homestead and everything fine.
And when I upload my code to production server and make new username of database,

And GRANT 
`grant all on drns.* to drns@localhost identified by 'drns****';`

Changed .env to

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:695XOiuHsxXXXXXXXXXXXLOX9gBE74=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://myip/

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=drns
DB_USERNAME=drns
DB_PASSWORD=drns****
```

Run artisan `php artisan route:cache && php artisan config:cache && php artisan view:clear`

Then I test my website, Every function in controller [create/update] it work usual,
But In function update on Document controler said error about homestead username

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('homestead'@'%') does not exist 
(SQL: update `documents` set `revision` = `revision` + 1, `number` = 0001.13 / 1, `title` = test, `urgency` = normal, `updated_at` = 2017-04-20 02:41:54 where `id` = 68)
```

My code

```
public function update(DocumentRequest $request, $id)
{
    $document =  Document::findOrFail($id);

    if ($document->increment('revision', 1, [
        'number' => $request->get('number'),
        'title' => $request->get('title'),
        'urgency' => $request->get('urgency')]))
    {

        return redirect()->route('document.show', $id);
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Can't update!');
}
```

Another controller in update function like these, But it not any error.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mittensoff from laracast help me to found the solution,

I create trigger in database[homestead] and dump database to server the definer is `homestead@%` it not changed. So, I change definer to username on database server then work correct.

Comment: I had a similar issue, I used a dump file with a View creation.. The user was different from the one on my env.